# If I'm expecting ether and provide the wrong address, what happens?

Tags: transactions

When expecting to receive ether from someone, is the ether lost if i provided a wrong address? Or can the transaction then not compute?

Answer (score 5):

The Ether would only be lost if the wrong address provided is also a valid address which would allow the transaction to confirm.

Please note that a valid address does not require that the address was generated from a private key. It only means that the address matches the format required for a valid address.

Ether cannot be lost if it is sent to an invalid address. Ether sent to an invalid address will not result in blockchain confirmation.

Comment: Please note that a valid address doesn't mean one generated from a private key. It only means that the address matches the format required for an address. So if you mistakenly swap two digits, the address is valid but as no private key corresponds to it, the ether will be stuck in it for ever. Sorry.